# Ubuntu | Nodejs | Secure location for SSL certificates?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, server, ssl-certificate

I have a nodeStatic app on an ubuntu server.

A domain links to the server.

Now I need to add SSL certificates:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/privatekey.pem').toString(),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/certificate.pem').toString()
};

var fileServer = new(nodeStatic.Server)();
var app = http.createServer(options, function(req, res) { 
  fileServer.serve(req, res);
}).listen(80);
```

The thing is they are not secure in the folder with the app, or am I wrong?

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

The app is in `var/www/myapp`

Anyone could open the contents of my certificates in the webbrowser with `example.com/ssl/privatekey.pem`

What is a good practise to serve the certificates and keep everything secure? Put them on the same level as index.js, or even further above? Is this secure?

Bonus question:

Kind of a general question, but the server is fresh, what shall I configure to keep everything secure? A good link on the topic would do it.

Comment: Move them above the webroot, never store anything in the webroot that contains important information, I'd even say move the static files to a subfolder and make that the webroot. Also install a firewall and only expose the ports you need, there's a lot that goes into security however you can find tons of tutorials online.

Comment: If you want to keep your server somewhat secure you should build a nice iptables firewall, configure your SSH properly and keep everything up-to-date. Mind the proxy configs in general, you don't want to leak something like certificates or passwords or allow people to browse your server at all.
I'd say go and check out the security page on the Arch wiki and look out for hardening guides in generals as this topic always changes.

Comment: Note that, on Linux and Unix, they are "directories" and not the Windows-ism of "folders" which is not the same thing.